# Error Uploading data to deployed model for prediction from appengine. works fine from local system

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-prediction, google-cloud-ml-engine

I am facing problem Uploading data from appengine to deployed model for prediction. The function works fine from my local system, But when I deploy the application I get some error saying that data is not Json Serializable.I don't  understand this any help will be appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
#convert Image to bse64 encoding
img = base64.b64encode(open("Images-Predict/"+filename, "rb").read());
#convert to valid json data
json_data={"key":"0", "image_bytes": {"b64": img}}

#Calling model for prediction
response = service.projects().predict(
    name=name,
    body={'instances': [json_data]}
).execute()
```

## Output Log from appengine[`log file`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ihhat.png)

[image: <code>log file</code>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `img` is bytes, so try converting to string:

```
img = img.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried that but again It works from local system, I thought it should work this time from App-Engine as well, but again the same error data not serializable. It works when I call the model from Terminal using the same img encoding.

Comment: It worked for me after saving the data into Json file using string encoding. Thanks for your help